# How do use multiple jQuery events with one id?

Tags: jquery

When this object is clicked i want it to be replaced with the returned value of this anonymous function.

```
$("#awayName").click.replaceWith(function() {
    var name1 = prompt("Enter a new name for Away Team, Please!");
    return name1;
});
```

Comment: And you're sure you're not just trying to change the text, and not the entire element ?

Comment: One option: http://jsfiddle.net/bJqXY/

Comment: `$("#awayName").click.replaceWith` is syntactically wrong. http://api.jquery.com/click

Comment: i just want to replace the text that is associated with the id but it has to be when they click the text. when they click the text a prompt when pop up asking them for a new name to replace the text with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work, if I don't missunderstand you.

```
$("#awayName").click(function() {
    var name1=prompt("Enter a new name for Away Team, Please!");
    $(this).text(name1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
$("#awayName").click(function() {
   $(this).replaceWith(prompt("Enter a new name for Away Team, Please!"));
});
```

Comment: Nope, it will not. replaceWith is meant for replacing elements with elements, not text with text.

Comment: @KevinB http://jsfiddle.net/Yzf96/ ... Okay, after your edit, your intention is clearer.

Comment: @Derija93 click it again after the first time.

Comment: @KevinB The OP never said that the click event has to be triggered twice. ;P